# How to start a new poll only after answering for a previous one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a simple code here. Im using https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api telegram framework to make my first bot. I have array with 10 questions in it. So i can't understarnd what should i do if i want to start a new poll only after user answered for a previous one? My current code just list all 10 polls when i use /start. Here is my code (i used snippet cos its working correct only in this way):

```html
bot.onText(/\/start (.+)/, (msg, [source, match]) => {
    const { id } = msg.chat
    if (match === test1Code){
        for (let i=0; i<test1Questions.length; i++){
            bot.sendPoll(id, test1Questions[i], pollOptions, {
                is_anonymous: false
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have tried to build a conversational dialog? You need to keep chat state somewhere.

Comment: In your backend you need to implement the logic to keep asking questions until (10 questions?) the quiz is completed and can take a different action (provide results? ask feedback?)

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of queue or flow manager. I can recommend [node-telegram-operation-manager](https://github.com/alexandercerutti/node-telegram-operation-manager/tree/master/examples) or [mau query engine](https://github.com/forfuturellc/mau/blob/master/example/telegram.js). Alternatively you can use a database to keep track of answers from a particular userId. With this approach you would send only the 1st poll. Then the rest of the polls would be sent based on the logic inside the poll event listener.